# Flex 4.5.1 mobile - show number pad only

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

Is it possile to show just the number pad to user when he clicks on a textinput (on an iphone/ipad)? Currently its showing the whole soft keyboard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible on the SDK 4.6. There is a property called `softKeyType="number"`.

Comment: This question was for the 4.5.1 SDK, this will not work in it.